# TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize crash

Tags: android

when i use

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.View, defStyle, 0);
a.getDimensionPixelSize(com.android.internal.R.styleable.View_padding, layout_unknow);
```

The `TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)` method crashed in Android 5.0

The log as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: you **could** solve it by posting your code

Comment: Are there other approaches that could be used?

Comment: yes, but only if there is someone on SO that can read your minds...

Comment: Maybe you can! ha-ha

Comment: sorry unfortunately i can't

Comment: com.android.internal.R.styleable.View is internal, you cannot use it

Comment: if I can't use com.android.internal.R.styleable.View ,How can i get instance variable 'a'

Comment: int[] attrs = {android.R.styleable.View_padding};

Comment: Sorry,buddy,styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: ooops android.R.attr.padding